# Can we add the custom view or the pulse ring animation around the marker in google maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have to add a pulse ring animation around a marker. As I see there is only NSObject in GOOGLEMAPS so we cannot add up a view . I have also tried to change or animate the scale of the marker but the scale change did not happen. Can anybody help me with this thing?

Comment: please explain more about your code & show a little of your code

Comment: You can use it using MKAnotationView

Comment: I cannot use up  MKMapkit . i am told to do it with google maps

Comment: DUPLICATE -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529248/how-set-custom-annotation-markers-animated-rings-around-a-point-on-gmsmapview/29912964#29912964

Comment: check with this ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41185450/4831524

Answer (score 1):

I've worked quite a bit with clustering markers with Google Maps for iOS SDK. `GMSMapView` uses OpenGL to render the markers on the map corresponding to the data points added via `GMSMarker`s. They provide a basic pop animation on appearance, but nothing else.

Without tracking `GMSMarker` movements and adding/keeping track of your own UIViews on the `GMSMapView`, this doesn't seem possible. `GMSMarker` lets the user specify a `UIImage` to replace the default marker image, but not animate the rendered `UIImage`, as the `GMSMapView` is backed by OpenGL. It is quite limiting- clustering markers was difficult because you cannot replace the default `GMSMarker` image with just a `UIView`. It HAS to be a `UIImage`.

Comment: UIImage cannot do the animation.Is there any way out.

Comment: I have only seen the pop and opacity animation on google maps. Is there any way to use any CAAnimation or CALayer on google maps to do Pulse Animation