# animated user location circle swift 3 + Google map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift3

Swift 3 and Google maps

How can I draw on Google's Map an animated couple of circles such as this image:

[image]

I already wrote the following code but still not this what i want

```
        let circleCenter : CLLocationCoordinate2D  = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(21.728178, 79.1201635);
    let circ = GMSCircle(position: circleCenter, radius: 10 * 1609.34)
    circ.fillColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.7, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
    circ.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 153/255, blue: 51/255, alpha: 0.5)
    circ.strokeWidth = 2.5;
    circ.map = self.googleMap;
```

Comment: Did you try a .gif image on pin place in google map?

Answer (score 0):

I found something near from what you are looking for from this answer link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41185450/2397493

Note : You have to download the included image at bottom of the answer and name it "pulse":

```
pulseRingImg.image = UIImage(named: "pulse")
```