# No visible @interface for 'UILabel' declares the selector 'addAnimation:forKey:'

Tags: objective-c, animation, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to add a 'pulsing' effect (scale in/out) to a label following this:

[ios - how to do a native "Pulse effect" animation on a UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083138/ios-how-to-do-a-native-pulse-effect-animation-on-a-uibutton)

But I am receiving the following error in XCode:

```
No visible @interface for 'UILabel' declares the selector 'addAnimation:forKey:'
```

The code (.h):

```
IBOutlet UILabel *SecondsLabel;
```

The code (.m):

```
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;

        theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale"];
        theAnimation.duration=1.0;
        theAnimation.repeatCount=HUGE_VALF;
        theAnimation.autoreverses=YES;
        theAnimation.fromValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
        theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
        [SecondsLabel addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"transform.scale"];
```

Comment: Variable names should begin with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be:

```
[SecondsLabel.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"transform.scale"];
```

not

```
[SecondsLabel addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"transform.scale"];
```

You have to use the layer of the label.