# Swift Pulse Animation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation, uitextfield

i'm trying to make a pulse animation, i've found this:
[How to do a native "Pulse effect" animation on a UIButton - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083138/ios-how-to-do-a-native-pulse-effect-animation-on-a-uibutton)
and it was useful, but i need something else,
so i have textfield, `UITextField` which has border,
when you focus on it i want the border to change color, but in specific way

I want it to start from center and then spread, I could not find the animation so i will try to demonstrate it via text: `B = Black`, `Y = Yellow`.

this is the border:

```
BBBBBBB
```

border gets focused:

```
BBBYBBB
BBYYYBB
BYYYYYB
YYYYYYY
```

animation is over, focus lost:

```
BYYYYYB
BBYYYBB
BBBYBBB
BBBBBBB
```

my code looks something like this:

```
let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
pulseAnimation.duration = 3
pulseAnimation.fromValue = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
pulseAnimation.toValue = UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor
pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEasInEaseOut)
pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
//pulseAnimation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX
x.layer.sublayers![0].addAnimation(pulseAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

it works but i need it to do something else

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This animation continually pulses from 0 to 1 opacity over 3 seconds:

```
let pulseAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
pulseAnimation.duration = 3
pulseAnimation.fromValue = 0
pulseAnimation.toValue = 1
pulseAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
pulseAnimation.autoreverses = true
pulseAnimation.repeatCount = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
self.view.layer.add(pulseAnimation, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: This is useful but isn't it something other than what was asked for? Or was the question modified?